# eventRender not being triggered Fullcalendar ASP.net C# webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

I'm having an issue with displaying events on fullcalendar. I am using ASP.net webforms with C#. I have ashx handler which I am calling to load the values from the database and this is then being formatted into a json response that is being sent back. Below is the javascript being used to generate the calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// update Dialog


// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    header:
    {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'month,agendaDay,agendaWeek, prev,next'
    },
    height: 600,
    //contentHeight: auto,
    titleFormat: 'MMMM D YYYY',
    columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    handleWindowResize: true,
    allDaySlot: true,
    minTime: '09:00:00',
    maxTime: '18:00:00',
    slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
    slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',
    firstDay: 1,
    weekends: false,
    hiddenDays: [6, 7],
    selectHelper: true,
    select: selectDate,
    editable: true,
    eventDrop: eventDropped,
    eventResize: eventResized,
    events: {
        url: 'JsonResponse.ashx',
        color: 'yellow',
        error: function () {
            alert('Error while Getting events!');
        }
    },

    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        console.log("here");
        //alert(event.title);
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description,
            style: {
                border: {
                    width: 1,
                    radius: 3,
                    color: '#2779AA'

                },
                padding: 10,
                textAlign: 'center',
                tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                name: 'cream' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error while Getting events!');
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('Success!');
            }

        });
    }


});

});
```

This is the JSON response I am getting in the browser network trace:

"{"id":8,"title":"tester","start":"2018-01-30","end":"2018-01-30","allday":"false","description":"tester"}"

ASHX file used to generate the JSON:

```
{


public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    start = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["start"]);
    end = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["end"]);


    String result = String.Empty;

    result += "\"[";
    eventSerializer newEvent = new eventSerializer();
    List<int> idList = new List<int>();
    foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end))
    {

        String allDay = "true";
        if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
        {

            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = "false";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
                && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = "false";
            }
        }

        newEvent.id = cevent.id;
        newEvent.title = cevent.title;
        newEvent.start = cevent.start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");;
        newEvent.end = cevent.end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");;
        newEvent.allday = allDay;
        newEvent.description = cevent.description;

    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonData = js.Serialize(newEvent);
    context.Response.Write(jsonData);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{


    long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
    return epoch;

}

}

public class eventSerializer
{

public int id;
public string title;
public string start;
public string end;
public string allday;
public string description;
}
```

I have attempted to add a console.log into the eventRender function and it doesn't seem to be getting triggered. The events are not being added to the calendar either. I am not getting any errors.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your JSON is invalid. Show the code you're using to generate it.

Comment: @ADyson according to JSON lint this is valid?

Comment: Well yes in the sense it's just all one single string. JSONLint just sees it as one big variable. But it's not parseable as an array, which is what fullCalendar is expecting. Why in the name of `<insert deity here>` are you building your JSON manually by concatenating strings? use JSON.NET or a similar tool to serialise your data automatically into valid JSON, with none of the hassle and without being prone to basic syntax errors like this. Even before JSON.NET existed (many years now), .NET has had other JSON serialiser tools built in. It's never been necessary to take this kind of approach.

Comment: @ADyson that makes sense then. I don't have much experience with JSON and Javascript and I have been following an online example, which seems to be outdated. Can you give me an idea of how to use JSON.net to build my JSON?

Comment: There's actually an example right there on the home page of the library: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json . Plenty in the documentation too, and probably plastered all over the internet if you try. I'm sure you can apply the same principle fairly easily to your list of events (hint: "list"). The nice thing about it is, you only need to know C#, you don't really need to know much at all about JSON. Give it a try, if you get stuck, update your question here with your new code and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Adyson thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code to serialize the json, but I'm still not seeing the event on the calendar. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: your code overwrites newEvent every time you loop. You'll end up with at most 1 event in your JSON, and it won't be in an array. Use your browser tools to check what the JSON looks like now when it comes from the server. Remember my hint before about lists? Also I would recommend JSON.NET over JavaScriptSerializer, and so would Microsoft - they set it by default now in new ASP.NET projects.

Comment: I appreciate that I need to create a list of event objects. However I don't think that's the issue with the event not displaying on the calendar. To me it seems as though the eventRender is not being fired. I updated the response I am getting in the browser.

Comment: "I appreciate that I need to create a list of event objects"...then, may I ask, why didn't you? You need to be serialising a `List<eventSerialiser>` or an `eventSerializer[]` (list of array), not a single object. This would produce a JSON array as the result. The chain of cause and effect is fairly clear - eventRender doesn't run because fullCalendar cannot find any events to render within the data you're giving it. I can't find any because you didn't supply a list (i.e. array) of events that it expects. Even if your array turns out only to contain one event, it must still be an array

Comment: Also, you new output, if that it literally what you're seeing in your response, really isn't even valid JSON this time, never mind JSON which fullCalendar would expect to see.  The double quotes at either end should not be there. They attempt to make it a single string again, but this time that fails because of the double quotes round the values, (which are in the correct place). I'm not sure what's adding the quotes, must be to do with how the ashx works  - the JavaScriptSerializer wouldn't do that I don't think. Let me think about it.

Comment: Interesting I made my own ashx handler with the exact same code (apart from subbing the DAO object for a static one) and it produces `{"id":8,"title":"tester","start":"2018-01-30","end":"2018-01-30","allday":"true","description":"tester"}` **without** the quotes. Are you adding the quotes personally just for displaying in this question? If so, please don't, it's confusing. If that's the real output of your code, then that's a bit strange, I can't reproduce it

Comment: Apologies I must have added the quotes myself when editing the question.

Comment: Ok, so then the only error is a logical one, i.e. not outputting an array. I'm just working on an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ADyson it appears that the issue was to do with the JSON not being returned in the correct format. After adding the JSON into a list and serializing the list the events are showing on the calendar. See below for the updated ASHX.

```
public class JsonResponse : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    start = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["start"]);
    end = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["end"]);

    List<int> idList = new List<int>();
    List<object> eventList = new List<object>();

    foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end))
    {
        eventSerializer newEvent = new eventSerializer();

        bool allDay = true;
        if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
        {

            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = true;
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
                && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = true;
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = false;
            }
        }

        idList.Add(cevent.id);

        newEvent.id = cevent.id;
        newEvent.title = cevent.title;
        newEvent.start = cevent.start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        newEvent.end = cevent.end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        newEvent.allDay = allDay;
        newEvent.description = cevent.description;

        eventList.Add(newEvent);
    }

    //store list of event ids in Session, so that it can be accessed in web methods
    context.Session["idList"] = idList;

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonData = js.Serialize(eventList);
    context.Response.Write(jsonData);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
    return epoch;
}

}

public class eventSerializer
{
public int id;
public string title;
public string start;
public string end;
public bool allDay;
public string description;
}
```

Comment: beat me to it! The code could be optimised a bit more (e.g. `allday` needs to be `allDay` to take effect in fullCalendar, and also the value needs to be a bool not a string (i.e. `true` not `"true"`), plus I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way to determine whether a DateTime has a time component or not, but other than that it looks like you're up and running. Good stuff.